# Android AdMob implementation play-services glitching the app?

Tags: android, admob, build.gradle

I'm trying to add AdMob to my app. I added the line below to build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
```

However, after syncing, I started the app but it close up when i try to open it .

Answer (score 0):

Add to manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```